# Почему не получается прикрепить onAction к TextField

Tags: java, fxml

[![TextField в котроллере импортирован не из Swing.][1]][1]

import javafx.scene.control.TextField; Подскажите пожалуйста где ошибка и как все это исправить
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh5L9.png

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас в контроллере `YouController` (на изображении не видно есть ли в теге AnchorPane поле `fx:controller="com.pack.controllers.YouController"`) действительно есть метод `sendSMTH` то он должен объявляться в `fxml` через `#` - то есть `onAction="#sendSMTH"`